# Real time update of GUI Graph

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-guide

I have made a simulink model and am running it through MATLAB GUI which contains a BLDC motor and a PI controller which controls its speed, now the problem is that the output apeed graph is updated when i stop the simulation i want it update it self in run time

```
% Update the string on the pushbutton
set(handles.Startstopbutton,'String','Start Simulation')

% Plot results from workspace after simulation
x = evalin('base','Scope(:,1)');
y = evalin('base','Scope(:,2)');
pHandles = plot(x,y,'Parent',handles.axesplot);
```

thats my graph update function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to have a MATLAB UI interact with a Simulink model as it is running, including

1. using a custom S-Function to pass data to the UI at each time step
2. using Event Listeners set up to listen for block (signals) as they change.

The [Use MATLAB GUI's with Simulink Models](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/06/01/use-matlab-guis-with-simulink-models/) blog discusses the approaches in more detail.